# SQL constraint on existing table - unique combination of values only when another column is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a pre-existing SQL Server table structured similarly to this:

```
[Username]   [Gateway]   [Code]   [ActiveTo]   [OrgId]  
------------------------------------------------------
user1        gateway      50        Null        100
user1        gateway      50        Null        101
user2        gateway2     51        Null        102
user3        gateway3     52       12/08/17     103
```

This table already has duplicate combinations of Username, gateway and code. I want to add a constraint such that any new users added have a unique combination of [Username], [Gateway] and [Code] but that ignores two pre-existing duplicates such as the two user1 entries above (not ignoring new entries that match pre-existing ones).

But I only want this to be applied when the duplicate's [ActiveTo] value is null (new entries have `ActiveTo` as null by default).

So applying the constraint to the table above would ignore the two user1 duplicates.

Then adding a row [user2], [gateway2], [52], [Null], [104] would be fine.

Then adding a row [user2], [gateway2], [51], [Null], [105] would throw an error.

But then adding row [user3], [gateway3], [52], [Null], [106] would be fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are we allowed to extend the table? Constraints should generally be re-apply-able at any time, so the "temporal" requirement (existing rows) would better be modelled as a new column which explicitly marks the rows to not consider (a very poor alternative is to base it on the OrgId, if we're guaranteed that it will always grow and we know the value to use when the constraint is applied)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique index :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_name_index_1 on table_name(Username, Gateway, Code) WHERE ActiveTo IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Question has been asked in respect to SQL Server not Oracle.

Comment: I think that only works with oracle though. With sql-server, I'm getting error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.'

Comment: try CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_name_index_1 on table_name(Username, Gateway, Code) WHERE ActiveTo IS NOT NULL

Comment: This causes this error:The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'Core.SFTPHost2HostConfig' and the index name 'table_name_index_1'. The duplicate key value is (151, mockbanksftp, 0).

Comment: Because there are pre-existing dupllicates. Thanks anyway.